# How to calculate the data in JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The essence is that I have json file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "username": "Antony",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "like": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "like": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "like": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "like": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "Janet",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "like": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "like": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "like": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "like": 1
            }
        ]
    },.......
```

I need to count how many "likes", have each user.
ie:
For example, take the first id == 0.
We pass on the object, which can be very much and look:
If id == 0 and like == 1, add 1 to the array.
In the end, I must have:
**usersWithLikes [id User] = number of likes for all objects**
For example:

> usersWithLikes [0] = 3
>
> usersWithLikes [1] = 1
>
> usersWithLikes [2] = 4
>
> usersWithLikes [3] = 0

At the moment, I think so:

thumbsUp_data - json data

```
var usersWithLikes = thumbsUp_data.map(function(user_data){
                    return user_data.users.filter(function(value){
                        return value.like == 1;
                    }).length;
                });
```

**But this is not correct, because it considers how many likes the object.
Help with the decision ...**

Comment: Why minuses?
I don't understaand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter out the user object, grab the first element of the returned array and then filter on that object's user array for `like === 1` returning it's length;

```
function howManyLikes(id) {
  return arr.filter(function (user) {
    return user.id === id;
  })[0].users.filter(function (el) {
    return el.like === 1;
  }).length;
}

howManyLikes(1); // 3
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xb80k5nv/)

Answer (score 0):

```
thumbsUp_data.forEach(function(data) {
    data.users.forEach(function(value) {
        usersWithLikes[value.id] = usersWithLikes[value.id] || 0;
        usersWithLikes[value.id] += value.like;
    });
});
```

Thats all, it's a solution!